# Kivy positioning of elements

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

**I don't understand how to make the blk be full screen and the items are sorted from top to bottom instead of bottom**.

Here is what the program looks like with the following code:

[image: Here is what the program looks like with the following code]

This is what I need:

[image: This is what I need]

items.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

Window.size = (430, 930)

class ItemsScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ItemsApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return ItemsScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Press Start 2P",
                    fn_regular='./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    ItemsApp().run()
```

item.kv

```
<ItemsScreen@Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 40
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            font_name: "Press Start 2P"
            text: 'айтеми'
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 30
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.3, 1
                ItemType1:
                ItemType1:
                ItemType1:

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 30
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.3, 1
                ItemType2:
                ItemType2:

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 30
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.3, 1
                ItemType3:
                ItemType3:
                ItemType3:
                ItemType3:


<ItemType1@Button>
    text: 'New Button'
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    background_normal: ''
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 220, 220
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 1}

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 96/255, 21/255, 21/255, 0.50
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [50]
        Color:
            rgba: 168/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rounded_rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 50)
```

I have no idea, I tried to use size_hint, but nothing worked. Can you tell me how to do it as in the 2nd photo

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
            Widget:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 200
```

at the end of each of your vertical `BoxLayouts` enough times so that each of the 3 `BoxLayouts` have the same number of children.